# While Loop and update data

Tags: php, mysql, email, loops, while-loop

Well, Im trying to send and email to users in my database who have "reserved a Code." But I need to send it all of them at the same time and then update the table.

When I test the next script it only sends and updates One row, it doesn't make the loop.

```
while ($result25 = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT * FROM santaterra WHERE Fecha='$today' AND Status='Reserved'"))
{
    $row25 = mysqli_fetch_array($result25);
    $username25=$row25['Solicitud'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE Usuario = '$username25'"); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $nuevosaldo = $misaldo - $precio;

    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET Value='$nuevosaldo' WHERE Usuario='$username25'");

    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE santaterra SET Status='Pagado' WHERE Solicitud='$username25'AND Fecha='$today'");

   $header = 'From: ' . $cuenta . " \r\n";
   $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
   $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
   $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

   $mensaje = " This is an example\r\n";

   mail($username25, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $header);

    mysqli_close($con);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
while ($result25 = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT * FROM santaterra WHERE Fecha='$today' AND Status='Reserved'"))
```

Your loop will never end as you are doing the same query over and over and over.

You need to do the query once and then fetch rows until there are no more:

```
$result25 = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT * FROM santaterra WHERE Fecha='$today' AND Status='Reserved'");
while ($row25 = mysqli_fetch_array($result25);) {
  ...
```

Apart from that you should use prepared statements to avoid sql injection and you should use a `JOIN` in sql so that you only have to do one query and not another query in the loop.

Comment: Thanks Mr. I took your advice, but still only updates the first row in the table. I need to update the first one, and send and email, then The second one and so on.. Whats happening with the loop?

Answer (score 0):

your while statement should be:
`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: In that way the While Loop will not recognize the change in the database. It still only updates the first row in the table. I need to update the first one, and send and email, then The second one and so on..